# FDF to PDF Server Application Unavailable

Tags: asp.net, fdf

I have a custom built CRM that is 99% written in Classic ASP/VBScript.  Currently we use a FDF to PDF script that generates a bunch of PDF files (depending on which PDF you are choosing to merge.)

Almost exactly the same time every day, at around 9:30 AM my users can no longer use the function as the error "Server Application Unavailable" appears when they try to use the function.  The error then may happen randomly or nearly every 2 hours thereafter - but it depends on usage.  In order for me to fix this, I have to either restart IIS, or Recycle the App Pool.

The App Pool that the site resides is independent of all other applications on the server.

The script was written in .NET by a 3rd party company and I can post the code here if required.

There is nothing in Event Log, and I'm unable to find any logs or indications as to what the problem may be.  Any ideas?

Comment: If anyone needs any additional information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application pool's idle timeout is set to 120 minutes, this could explain this issue appearing every two hours. I have had issues where certain long-running processes idle-out and are shut down by IIS.

**EDIT:**

I just poked around, and I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/175303/iis-application-pools-and-event-logs), which looks promising.

Comment: @Mark Avenius 

It's not exactly 2 hours, but I understand what you're saying.  I disabled the idle shutdown for the interim.  Anywhere I can find logs of any of this?

Comment: Thanks Mark - I believe that answers my question.  I'm going to keep this question open and unanswered for the meantime I want to see if the changes made actually solve the issue.

Also - I didn't even know there were other "Stack" sites!  I've been asking all my questions here instead of the approprate ones!

Comment: @RogueSpear: You're welcome! Yes, there is quite a bit of information available on the StackExchange community. Welcome, and good luck!

Comment: Today will tell, Mark - if in fact inactivity was indeed my problem.

Comment: Just an update - I haven't had the problem reappear after several hours, I think this may have resolved the issue.  Thanks Mark!

Comment: Mark - Bad news.  This problem is now showing more frequently.  I had initially thought this issue was resolved, but it is reappearing.  I have not changed any settings or modified anything on the server-side.  Any further ideas by chance?